Gaps between bottom bricks exterior of home
Between every 2 or 3 bricks on the bottom row of the outside of my home there is a gap without cement or little to no filler. I’ve noticed ants trying to build mounds and other bugs getting inside of the hole. Could there be any reason for gaps? Should I seal them up?

They are called weeping holes. They are there to allow any water/moisture behind the brick to escape/run out.
Can stuff some window screening into the holes to keep bugs out.  The type of ants might matter.  Termites/carpenter ants should have professional pest removal.
